# IntelliJ 2023.2.2 can not create new Spingboot Project with Java 11

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Problem is no option to choose as Java 11 or Java 8 when i create new Spring Boot Project in IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2023.2.2 and using trial version. They only give me option of Java 17 and 21 to choose. Did they end support for Java 11 and 8 or they limit my choice because i'm using trial ?

What is the reason of this or anyway to create new Spring Boot project with java 11. I have SDK of Java 11 and Java 17 already

Here you can see the photo: https://prnt.sc/027NhFh6LsTJ

Comment: This is not related to the IDE. I think you will need Java 17 or higher for Spring Boot 3.0.  See https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA's Spring Boot project creation functionality is based on what's provided by the underlying open-source Spring Initializr project (https://github.com/spring-io/initializr). Limiting support for older Java versions is their call, not the IDE's. As a workaround, you can create the project using a higher version of Java, then edit the pom.xml yourself and reload the dependencies. For a more detailed explanation and suggestions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77570193/alternative-website-for-spring-initializr-for-java-8-start-spring-io-now-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA's Spring Boot project creation functionality is based on what's provided by the underlying open-source [Spring Initializr project](https://github.com/spring-io/initializr). Requiring higher versions of Java is their call, it has nothing to do with the IDE.

As a workaround, you can create the project in IDEA using higher versions of Java/Spring, then change the versions in the `pom.xml` manually and reload the dependencies to match your setup.

For a more detailed explanation and instructions, see [Alternative website for Spring Initializr for java 8? (start.spring.io now only allow Java 17+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77570193/alternative-website-for-spring-initializr-for-java-8-start-spring-io-now-only)